# Getting OAuth token via Windows application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, oauth-2.0

We need to access several web services (not a specific one) and need to build an application in which the user can retrieve the needed refresh token.

This Windows native .NET application (so not a web app) needs to do the following:

- Present the user a window with a web browser control that shows the login page of the targeted web service.

  - After the user has logged in to the web service and gave permission, the Windows application should be able to receive the token from the webservice (so the application should act like it would be a webpage used for the redirect url).

The overal purpose is to generate a new token and receive that in my application.

I've searched a lot, but couldn't find a simple bare-bone example. I only need to know how to receive the token (redirect url).

Could you give me an example and/or link to such an example (C# or VB).

Comment: Maybe this link can help you. https://blog.appharbor.com/2012/06/21/oauth-for-net-desktop-applications

Comment: It is unclear whether you want to generate the *token* or just receive a generated token (from the service)

Comment: @bit I updated the question.